# Elongation due to self weight - why the load acting on an element is gradually applied load?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, civil-engineering, structural-analysis

Consider a bar of uniform circular cross-section. We are interested in knowing the elongation of this bar due to its self-weight. This is a common problem in an undergraduate course on Mechanics of Solids.

This is how I have seen it solved in books - [Elongation of a bar due to its self-weight](https://www.ques10.com/p/8788/derive-an-expression-for-the-elongation-due-to-s-1/)

Wherever I have seen such a problem, it's stated pretty vaguely. It just says to determine the elongation of the bar and gives the relevant parameters, but no info on how the bar is set up. Which I feel is the main cause of my doubt.

---

Doubt:

To find the elongation, the [link](https://www.ques10.com/p/8788/derive-an-expression-for-the-elongation-due-to-s-1/) has considered an element of thickness dy at y and determined the elongation produced in that element. The force acting on this element is taken as the weight of the part of the bar below it, which is $P_y =\rho Ayg$. To find the elongation in this element, it has then used the $\frac{PL}{AE}$ formula,

$$\delta (\Delta L)= \frac{P_y dx}{AE}$$

The link has then put the value of $P_y$ and integrated from 0 to L to get the total change in length.

The formula $\frac{PL}{AE}$ is valid only when the load P applied is gradual (that is it is a gradually applied load that increases from 0 to P). **How did we know in the above case that the load $P_y =\rho Ayg$ was gradually acting on the element?** Because only when Py acts gradually can we use this formula - $\frac{PL}{AE}$.

Comment: How would it be a dynamic load?

Comment: @SolarMike No, I mean, shouldn't it be a suddenly applied load? The weight instantly acts on the element the moment we make the bar vertical. However, the formula is only valid when the load is gradual, increases from 0 to Px, in some time.

Comment: I don't understand your question and the setup of the bar. What is your definition of "gradual"? Was the bar fixed on the ceiling?

Comment: This is a steady state analysis. If you want to include transient effects, it would be much more complex. Even though steady state basically does not exist in reality, it is still very useful concept for analysing real structures.

Comment: @r13 I have edited the question, to hopefully make it more clear.

Comment: @TomášLétal I think I'm not doing a good job in explaining my query, I've made an edit though. What I'm interested in is that even if we consider the simple scenario of steady state, we have used the formula PL/AE to determine the elongation of the little element, my question is how do we know $P_y$, which is the force on the element was gradually acting? because the formula Pl/AE can only be used for a gradually applied load P.

Comment: @HarshitRajput How would you define "gradually acting"?

Comment: @TomášLétal Like the load increases from 0 to $P_y$, in some time, i.e. it is slowly increasing to the maximum value.

Comment: @HarshitRajput I think your question is similar to asking how do we know the bar's cross section area is $A$? We just assume it is for the purpose of modelling. If the reality does not differ much from the model's assumption, then the model might be useful. Nevertheless, there will always be some deviations.

Comment: Load Py=ρAyg = mg = weight. Do your feet feel any change when standing still? Now try jumping up in the air and falling back on your feet, how do your feet feel at the instant they touch the ground? How about 10 seconds later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "problem" is that you are solving a problem in the stationary regime, where dynamic effects are neglected.

You are thinking on the transient regime. And in any case, if you consider even the most basic damping for the set-up, it will very quickly converge to the stationary answer.

Comment: I have made some edits to the question, please have a look. Even if we took the most basic case of stationary regime, I still don't understand how are we using the formula PL/AE to find the elongation of the element. This formula is only valid when load P is gradually applied, and I don't get how the load on the element Py is increasing from 0 to P gradually.

Comment: Because *gradually* is a relative term. Engineers use something called nondimensional time to characterize the nature of dynamic response and whether we can just ignore it and consider the quasistatic solutions. If you divided the rod's length by the speed of sound in the material, and factored in the material's internal damping characteristics, you can find a time in which the dynamics will dissipate to a level that can be ignored, and it won't take too long unless you have a well engineered brass bell.

Comment: @HarshitRajput I think your confusion stems from when the formula applies. It doen not apply if the load is applied gradually (that's one case), it applies when there is no dynamic effects present. So, in the case you are looking at, assuming even the slightest energy dissipation due to damping, d=PL/AE applies when t->infinity (i.e. a=v=0)

Comment: @Zegpi oh, I think I get it now. I thought of this example- I have a bar fixed on the ground (vertically) and I drop a weight on it from a height, when the weight hits the bar, it gives some compression greater than PL/AE but as the time goes it vibrates and eventually comes to rest. At rest, it will have a compression equal to PL/AE. Even though the system went through transient state we were able to use the PL/AE formula, because the rest compression will be the same as we would have got if the weight was added slowly on to the bar. Am i right?

Comment: @HarshitRajput Yes! you got it perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Yes if you attach the bar to the ceiling and release it very suddenly, then what you assume will happen and the bar will start to vibrate.

You need to use stiffness tensor, mass tensor, and continuum mechanics. which is going to be a research project.

For a rough quick estimate, I would replace the bar with a trapezoid tapering off as it goes down, and find the center of elasticity. and assume it is a simple spring vibrating under self-weight!

Or you can use FEM sofware.

Comment: Hi kamran, let's say we took a case where we released the bar slowly. How will then the load Py which acts on the little element act gradually? To find the element's elongation we have used PL/AE in which P has to be a gradually applied load. I have made some edits to the question to make it more clear.

Comment: @HarshitRajput, the elongation will be $ \delta L=\ int_{0}^{L}\frac{\rho *y*dy}{E} =\frac{\rho L^2}{2E}$.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a hammer and hit the end of a metal rod, it will ting. The noise is caused by the dynamical response. Once the noise has stopped, the rod is quiescent and the static solution is valid. So it won't take long for your rod to damp out any  dynamics. Most of the damping will be internal to the material.

Comment: I think I did not do a good job putting my point, I have made an edit please have a look. Even if the case was the simples one where we neglected the initial transient period, how did we conclude that the load Py which was acting on the element was a gradually acting one? The link that I have provided in the edited question is using the formula PL/AE and it can only be used when P is gradual.